# RAID1 Broken Mirroring

Tags: hard-drive, raid1, mirroring

I'm having a little server with Windows Small Business Server 2003. I'm using RAID1, via a **HighPoint Rocket RAID 1640** RAID-card, using two harddrives.

This week the server alarmed, and durig reboot I got the error-message **Broken Mirroring** [(User Manual page 30)](http://www.highpoint-tech.com/PDF/RR1640/RR1640_User_Manual.pdf). I had a few alternatives (see the manual), first I tried **Continue**, but the server restarted during boot. Next time I took **Power Off**, and replaced the oldest harddrive with a new one, and when I booted, I selected **Rebuild**. Then I selected the new harddrive to be the new one. The rebuild-procedure started and a progress bar at 0% showed up, but after a few seconds I got the message **Copy Failed!**, then the server booted and Windows Server started. Now it works fine.

But I guess that I'm just using one harddrive now, and it's not mirrored. I haven't touched the server since then (two days ago). What should I do now? I have no experience of this situation.

Anyone that have some guidance?

Comment: Does the controller still show the array as degraded?

Comment: No, it seams to work fine now, except that it is crashing very often.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RAID controller seams to work fine now. I haven't done anything more with it. Case closed.

Answer (score 0):

Most RAID controllers will show the status of the array and its member drives during the POST process at boot.  They usually have a way (Ctrl+I and Ctrl+M are popular) to access the RAID management with options for checking consistency and rebuilding drives.  I would try to get into that and perform the rebuild from the firmware tools before the OS loads and the system is busy.

Comment: Yes, that is what I tried.